# Integrating Google re-captcha in PHP existing form

Tags: php, recaptcha

Ok, I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out on my own, but have had no success. I am trying to get recaptcha to validate the captcha on the same page. I would rather have it check that the captcha is right before proceeding to the next page. I placed the call for the google js file in the head:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Then following the instructions I place the second piece at the end of the form like so:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="***************************************"></div>
```

So far so good. Now, the part that is kicking my *** is the server side integration. The code they supply is:

```
When your users submit the form where you integrated reCAPTCHA, you'll get
as part of the payload a string with the name "g-recaptcha-response". In 
order to check whether Google has verified that user, send a POST request
with these parameters:

URL: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
secret (required)   **********************************************
response (required) The value of 'g-recaptcha-response'.
remoteip    The end user's ip address.
```

I am really stumped as to how that part is supposed to work, like where does it go actually? I have checkout.php submitting to billing-checkout.php. Does that second part go into billing-checkout.php? If so, how do I make it work exactly? I hate feeling like a noob but I am very frustrated by this whole thing. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to make a cURL request to the supplied URL and either get a yay or a nay back.

```
<?php
$cp = curl_init("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
$fields = array(
    'secret' => YOUR_RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY,
    'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],
    'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
);
curl_setopt($cp, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($cp, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($cp, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($cp, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

$data = curl_exec($cp); // The response

curl_close($cp);

?>
```

Comment: Ok, i will give that a try and get back with you, thanks :)

Comment: Well I tried that but the captcha went to the next page anyway, even though I did not check the I am not a robot checkbox. Going to try this on the same page just in case it works.

Comment: Tried this part of the script on both the same and the page it is posting submit to. The captcha is not doing anything.

Comment: Well are you checking the response in your formhandler? The snippet is to be used within your handler code. `$data['success']` either returns `true` or `false` and you need to raise an error yourself accordingly

Comment: That was the missing part. I finally figured that out and it is working flawlessly. Thanks for all the assistance, it has been a learning experience for me for sure :)

Comment: me too, appreciate all yours and others help here on SO